# Problems exctracting text with PoDoFo

Tags: c++, podofo

I am new to PoDoFo and trying to extract the text content of a PDF file with it. I have essentially followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909634/c-podofo-how-can-i-convert-pdf-into-raw-txt-file?noredirect=1&lq=1&fbclid=IwAR2NU8EQ2Ma7kpL-jAKRl3gjNlfDbv4URbuTMd9PgqpGpLRDgzwKfMS2aC4) and it works fine with some PDFs but not with others. That is, **std::cout << str << ""** prints nothing. I have tried to change **if(a[i].IsString())** to **if(a[i].IsString() || a[i].IsHexString())** but this doesn't help. Any ideas at all about what could cause this? I'm out of ideas and a bit desperate. I know the text can be extracted with PDFminer.six in Python (and the files are just containing black on white text - nothing fancier) but I'd like to extract the text with with C++. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your post with more context: [mcve].

Comment: Recommendation: Take the [tour] and read [ask] and [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: I don't have any trouble extracting text from the example.pdf with PoDoFo. I can access the first line starting "This printout..." and also text in Table1 and the footnotes and the references. So no problem there. I have PDFs that are far less complex looking and I can't extract text from them! Any ideas what could be behind this?