# Podofo text coordinates

Tags: c++, pdf, podofo

I am now about to use PoDoFo to parse PDF.I have the source code pdofo-tools `podofotxtextract` available here : [podofotxtextract](https://github.com/mekentosj/podofo/tree/master/tools/podofotxtextract) file TextExtractor.cpp
.
I would change this code for get the text coordinates, after reading this post : [PoDoFo extract text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455081/podofo-extract-text-coords-from-a-pdf) and reading Adobe specification, to retrieve the contact information I need to use the operator `Tm`, this operator is matrix. 
So I added in the source code a new case like this

```
... other case in if( bTextBlock ) ....
else if( strcmp( pszToken, "Tm" ) == 0 )
{
     std::cout << "I have matrix here Tm " <<  std::endl;                   
}
....
```

This code works but I do not know how to display the values of the matrix.
Adobe specifies :
[image]

If anyone can help me

Comment: *"how to display the values of the matrix"* - for which purpose?

Comment: Hum I've find the solution ! PoDoFo provide `GetReal()` this function can be use with `std::stack<PdfVariant>`, with this function I finaly get coordinates of text

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read "PDF Succinctly" By Ryan Hodson (First google search takes you to it) and Acrobat (which was suggested in a similar question)
https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/pdf_reference_archives/PDFReference.pdf

First thing, you are missinterpreting how pdf are "coded".
Podofo will give you variants and tokens. You are supposed to stack variants and process them once you find a token (except for a few cases where the token opens or closes a block, which won't have any variant).

By the time you reach the Tm token you should have 6 variants staked, which will correspond to the positions of the matrix you pasted.